# How to pass multiple values from C program to shell script

Tags: c, shell, process, environment-variables

I have a shell script which does some basic functions and calls the c program with specific command line arguments for each operation.

The C program returns integer value indicating success or failure.

Now I have a situation, where the c program needs to couple of values and that needs to be accessed by the parent script. Is there any way this can be achieved? [Apart from storing the value in a temporary file and the script accessing the file to get the value]

Comment: maybe a pipe if the logic permits

Comment: Consider haring sample input and output, so that SO readers will understand the problem that you are trying to solve

Answer (score 1):

Let your C program write the values to its `stdout`, and use the *command substitution* shell feature to capture those values in the parent script, along the lines of

```
program_output=$(your_c_program with the arguments it needs)
```

`man bash` (and search for command substitution) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `excecl` command

```
int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);
```

Like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void main () {

   return execl ("/bin/pwd", "pwd", NULL);

}
```

Comment: May be my question is bit confusing. Let me give an example. Lets say I have a script test1.sh, from which I am calling an executable exe1. This exe1 (c program) will get some values say val1 and val2. These values should be returned back to the script test1.sh, so that I can continue with other operations on val1 and val2.

Answer (score 0):

yes there is, take a look at the exec system call, there are multiple functions that can help you achieve this, but basically you can execute a c program and pass it all arguments you want/need

https://linuxhint.com/exec_linux_system_call_c/

Comment: Basically the shell script is the parent which is calling C program. not the other way round.

Comment: let's say your executable is called main and you want to pass the following arguments to it: arg1, arg2 and arg3. you can do this by typing in the shell: ./main arg1 arg2 arg3